# CouchDB not responding while replication from PouchDB

Tags: javascript, angularjs, synchronization, couchdb, pouchdb

i'm trying to sync a PouchDB database with a CouchDB database setting live/retry options to true.

But when this process starts i cannot access CouchDB.

If i take a look at my browser console in the network section, all works about 5 seconds and then i see some requests never get a response.

I've tried to increase some options inside couchDB config like connection_timeout to 30000 and http_connections to 20000 but it still not working.

Do you have any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: did you solve this? I am having a similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47474384/couchdb-sync-access-on-google-app-engine