# CouchDB login access on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, authentication, synchronization, couchdb

I am running a CouchDB instance on Google App Engine. I have successfully [created a SSH tunnel to access Fauxton on it via localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47349446/how-do-i-access-fauxton-on-the-google-appengine-platform). I have enabled CORS and am using https. I have [added `NETWORK: *` to my cache manifest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23603658/angularjs-pouchdb-app-stops-syncing-to-couchdb-when-cache-manifest-added).

Now I need to sync my PouchDB data to my remote CouchDB database.

This related question [Couchdb sync access with userid and password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38780973/couchdb-sync-access-with-userid-and-password) shows how to pass in the userid and password on a CouchDB instance hosted on cloudant. (I've also checked all the other related questions.)

**Is there a similar method to use for doing this on Google App Engine?**

Something like this?

```
https://<api_key>:<key_passwd>@<username>.<my_ip_address>:5984/<db_name>
```

According to [PouchDB: getting started](https://pouchdb.com/getting-started.html) the format is `http://user:pass@myname.example.com/dbname`

I'm not sure if I should use the hostname (`myapp.appspot.com`) or the host's IP address though.

**Code in `application.js`**

```
PouchNotesObj = function (databasename, remoteorigin) {
    'use strict';

    Object.defineProperty(this, 'pdb', {writable: true});
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'remote', {writable: true});
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'formobject', {writable: true});
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'notetable', {writable: true});
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'searchformobject', {writable: true});
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'errordialog', {writable: true});
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'dbname', {writable: true});

    var databasename = 'myPdb';
    var remoteorigin = 'https://<IP ADDRESS>';


    this.dbname = databasename;
    this.pdb = new PouchDB(databasename);
    this.remote = remoteorigin + '/myPdb';

//from https://github.com/pouchdb-community/pouchdb-authentication/issues/121      
    var user = {
      name: 'admin',
      password: '<myPassword>'
    };
    var pouchOpts = {
      skipSetup: true
    };
    var ajaxOpts = {
      ajax: {
        headers: {
          Authorization: 'Basic ' + window.btoa(user.name + ':' + user.password)
        }
      }
    };
    this.remote.login(user.name, user.password, ajaxOpts).then(function() {
      return db.allDocs();
    }).then(function(docs) {
      console.log(docs);
    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.error(error);
    });

};
```

**`pouchdb.authentication.js`**

```
exports.login = utils.toPromise(function (username, password, opts, callback) {
  var db = this;
  if (typeof callback === 'undefined') {
    callback = opts;
    opts = {};
  }
  if (['http', 'https'].indexOf(db.type()) === -1) {
    return callback(new AuthError('this plugin only works for the http/https adapter'));
  }

  if (!username) {
    return callback(new AuthError('you must provide a username'));
  } else if (!password) {
    return callback(new AuthError('you must provide a password'));
  }

  var ajaxOpts = utils.extend(true, {
    method : 'POST',
    url : utils.getSessionUrl(db),
    headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    body : {name: username, password: password}
  }, opts.ajax || {});
  utils.ajax(ajaxOpts, wrapError(callback));
});
```

**Error message in Console**

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.remote.login is not a function
```

Comment: logged in with `var remoteorigin = 'https://username:password@ipaddress:5984';` and got error: `Sync Error:{"code":"ETIMEDOUT","status":0,"result":{"ok":false,"start_time":"2017-11-24T14:13:51.706Z","docs_read":0,"docs_written":0,"doc_write_failures":0,"errors":[],"status":"aborting","end_time":"2017-11-24T14:14:01.711Z","last_seq":0}}`

Comment: and the next time I deployed the app I got `500 Server Error`.

Comment: then tried `https://ipaddress:5984/dbname/` and got the following error: `GET https://ipaddress:5984/dbname/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [`ptitjes` on Github for an answer on what was going wrong with the `login()` function](https://github.com/pouchdb-community/pouchdb-authentication/issues/130#issuecomment-347164905):

> you are trying to call `login()` on a string (your `this.remote` is a
>   string). Hence the `TypeError: this.remote.login is not a function`. You
>   should have done: `this.remote = new PouchDB(remoteorigin + '/myPdb');`

(I find that confusing because the remote database is CouchDB, but there you go.)

**The login is now working but the sync still isn't working.**

**Login function**

```
PouchNotesObj = function (databasename, remoteorigin) {
'use strict';

Object.defineProperty(this, 'pdb', {writable: true});
Object.defineProperty(this, 'remote', {writable: true});
Object.defineProperty(this, 'formobject', {writable: true});
Object.defineProperty(this, 'notetable', {writable: true});
Object.defineProperty(this, 'searchformobject', {writable: true});
Object.defineProperty(this, 'errordialog', {writable: true});
Object.defineProperty(this, 'dbname', {writable: true});

var databasename = 'pouchnotes';
var remoteorigin = 'https://ip-address:5984';

this.dbname = databasename;
this.pdb = new PouchDB(databasename);
this.remote = new PouchDB(remoteorigin + '/pouchnotes');

var user = {
  name: 'admin',
  password: 'password'
};
var pouchOpts = {
  skipSetup: true
};
var ajaxOpts = {
  ajax: {
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Basic ' + window.btoa(user.name + ':' + user.password)
    }
  }
};

this.remote.login(user.name, user.password, ajaxOpts, function (err, response) {
  if (err) {
    if (err.name === 'unauthorized' || err.name === 'forbidden') {
      console.log('Unauthorised user');
    } else {
      //return this.remote.allDocs();
      console.log('Successful login');
    }
  }
});


var opts = {live: true};
this.pdb.replicate.to(this.remote, opts);
this.pdb.replicate.from(this.remote, opts);
};
```

**Sync function**

[See: Manav Manocha's version of PouchNotes on Github](https://github.com/manavmanocha/pouchnotes/)