# CouchDB sync error net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Tags: google-app-engine, synchronization, couchdb, pouchdb

I am trying to sync a local PouchDB instance with a remote CouchDB instance on Google App Engine.

I have [successfully logged in to the remote instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47474384/couchdb-login-access-on-google-app-engine), but I am getting the following error when I try to sync:

```
replication paused (e.g. user went offline)
pouchdb-6.3.4.min.js:9 GET https://<ipaddress>:6984/pouchnotes/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
```

**Sync function**

```
PouchNotesObj.prototype.syncnoteset = function (start, end) {
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    document.getElementById("syncbutton").innerHTML = "Syncing...";

    var i, 
    that = this, 

    options = { 
    doc_ids:['1450853987668']   
  };

    if(start){ options.startkey = start; }
    if(end){ options.endkey = end; }

    PouchDB.sync(this.dbname, this.remote, { retry: true })
    .on('change', function (info) {
       console.log('change');
        document.getElementById("syncbutton").innerHTML = "Sync Notes";
    }).on('paused', function () {
       console.log('replication paused (e.g. user went offline)');
        document.getElementById("syncbutton").innerHTML = "Sync Notes";
    }).on('active', function () {
       console.log('replicate resumed (e.g. user went back online)');
        document.getElementById("syncbutton").innerHTML = "Sync Notes";
    }).on('denied', function (info) {
       console.log('a document failed to replicate, e.g. due to permissions');
        document.getElementById("syncbutton").innerHTML = "Sync Notes";
    }).on('complete', function (info) {
      console.log("Sync Complete");
      document.getElementById("syncbutton").innerHTML = "Sync Notes";
      that.viewnoteset();
      that.formobject.reset();    
      that.show(that.formobject.dataset.show);
      that.hide(that.formobject.dataset.hide);
      var end = new Date().getTime();
      console.log("Time Taken - " + (end - start) + " ms");
    }).on('error', function (error) {
      console.log("Sync Error:" + JSON.stringify(error));  
      alert("Sync Error:" + error);
      that.showerror(error);
    });   

}
```

**Edited to add**: do I need to set this up?
[image: replication job config on Fauxton]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that [I had not configured the firewall correctly](https://docs.bitnami.com/google/faq/#how-to-open-the-server-ports-for-remote-access).

For anyone else who stumbles across this issue: you only need SSH tunnelling to access Fauxton on localhost. You don't need it to access the API.

If you want to [access the API via https, the port is 6984](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=48203146) (not 5984), and for a non-Google App Engine server, you need something like [Nginx set up to provide a SSL certificate](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/COUCHDB/Nginx+as+a+proxy). On Google App Engine, SSL certificates are provided.

But you still need to [configure CouchDB to enable SSL](https://docs.bitnami.com/virtual-machine/infrastructure/couchdb/#how-to-enable-ssl-for-https-on-couchdb).

[Thanks to the guys at the CouchDB user mailing list for their input](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/couchdb-user/201711.mbox/browser).